# How to center horizontally div inside parent div

Tags: html, css

How do I center a `div` horizontally inside its parent `div` with `CSS`?

```
<div id='parent' style='width: 100%;'>
 <div id='child' style='width: 50px; height: 100px;'>Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I am assuming the parent div has no width or a wide width, and the child div has a smaller width. The following will set the margin for the top and bottom to zero, and the sides to automatically fit. This centers the div.

```
div#child {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Mark. Do you know how to make it work in IE6? IE6 really sucks a lot, but still there are some people using it.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: as far as I remember, it does. What issues are you seeing? you might want to pop open a new question if there's some specific issue you're having which hasn't been touched on before. I don't have access to IE6 to check with though.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: actually having thought about it, I think in IE.old you also need to set `text-align: center;` on the `parent` div and then set it back to left (or whatever) for the `child` one. Not sure if that issue afflicts IE6...

Comment: @Mark & @Bakhtiyor for some reason i was having my `child` div seemingly shifted to the left--in comparison to browsers that are more standards compliant--in all versions of IE that i checked (IE6-8). And `text-align: center;` for the `parent` and `text-align: left;` for the `child` fixed it for all those versions.

Answer (score 12):

```
<div id='parent' style='width: 100%;text-align:center;'>
 <div id='child' style='width:50px; height:100px;margin:0px auto;'>Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution supports IE 6, but don't forget to add `text-align:left;` to the #child div

Comment: `text-align:center` to the child div or the parent div?

Answer (score 11):

```
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child-canvas {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just out of interest, if you want to center two or more divs (so they're side by side in the center), then here's how to do it:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the "auto" value for the left and right margins to let the browser distribute the available space equally at both sides of the inner div:

```
<div id='parent' style='width: 100%;'>
   <div id='child' style='width: 50px; height: 100px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto'>Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id='child' style='width: 50px; height: 100px; margin:0 auto;'>Text</div>
```