# Center div inside parent div

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to center a div inside a parent div based on the dimensions of the parent div. I have tried using:

```
display: inline-block;
```

because I have seen other questions where this was used to center the div but I am not having luck.

BOX1 should be centered insdie of test

```
<div class="tab-pane" id = "test">
    <div id="Box2"> 
        <h1> Graph Text </h1>
  </div>
    <div id="BOX1">
  </div>
</div>


#test {
    width:700px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
    position:relative;
}

#BOX1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgrey;  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#Box2{
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    position:absolute;
    left: 125px;
    z-index:2;
}

h1 {
  font: 25px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bahanson/xvL2qvx0/5/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center horizontally div inside parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952256/how-to-center-horizontally-div-inside-parent-div)

Comment: If the width and height of the parent div are reduced, is there a way to automatically scale down the width and height of the child div?

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center divs within divs, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L71ejnz7/)

```css
#test {
    width:700px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
    position:relative;
}

#BOX1 {
 margin:0 auto;
    width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 background: lightgrey; 
 position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}

#Box2{
   width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    position:absolute;
    left: 125px;
    z-index:2;
}

h1 {
  font: 25px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="tab-pane">
    
    <div id="BOX1">
  <div id="Box2"> 
        <h1> Graph Text </h1>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the box 1 css does what you want and will keep the child centered if the parent width changes.

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvL2qvx0/6/

If you don't need IE8 support you can just use:

```
left: calc(50% - 250px);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on normal flow and CSS positioning.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/cssglossary/g/bldefnormalflow.htm

But basically, a div will always position relative to the parent div.

If you add `margin: 0 auto;` to a div, it should horizontally position it within the parent div

Answer (score 0):

```css
#BOX1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:100px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: lightgrey;  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

use margin-left command to adjust it to the centre....

Answer (score 0):

Seen as though you are using absolute positioning you can simply give it a `top`,`right`,`left` and `bottom` of `0` and use `margin:auto` to centre it both horizontally and vertically.

This benefits from be able to use relative (percentage) sizing if you want *and* there's no maths involved. Furthermore, if you later change the dimensions (maybe via a media-query for mobile devices) you don't need to recalculate messy margins or offsets - just change the size and it will be centred.

```
#BOX1 {
    display: block;
    width: 500px; /* it will still work if you change the size */
    height: 300px; /* the dimensions could be percentages if you like */
    background: lightgrey;  
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xvL2qvx0/7/

```css
#test {
    width:700px;
    height: 500px;
    background: grey;
    position:relative;
}

#BOX1 {
    width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 background: lightgrey; 
 position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}

#Box2{
   width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: lightblue;
    position:absolute;
    left: 125px;
    z-index:2;
}

h1 {
  font: 25px Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane" id = "test">
    <div id="Box2"> 
        <h1> Graph Text </h1>
  </div>
    <div id="BOX1">
  </div>
</div>
```